# No "New event" button in SharePoint Calendar View of Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, view

I have created a custom SharePoint list definition. My template is a generic SPListItem. Each item has start and end values.

Now I have been given the requirement that I need to display the items in a calendar view. For this I have created following view for my list:

```
 <View BaseViewID="3" DisplayName="$Resources:Calendar;" Type="CALENDAR" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" XslLink="main.xsl" WebPartZoneID="Main" WebPartOrder="1" Url="MyCalendar.aspx" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>
    </JSLink>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Format="TimeOnly" Name="ActivityStartTime"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Format="TimeOnly" Name="ActivityEndTime"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ActivityProject"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ActivityStartTime" Ascending="TRUE"></FieldRef>
        <FieldRef Name="ActivityEndTime" Ascending="TRUE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink />
  </View>
```

The only problem with this approach is, I cannot get the "New event" button to show up if I hover over a day cell in month view.

[image]

If I create a event list in Sharepoint I get expected results. But if I use my custom list with a calendar view it doesn't. Does anybody know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone coming to this question, the solution was to put 106 in the type attribute in the list. This converted it from a generic list item list to a event list, which has this functionality OOTB.

Comment: Where do you modify the "type attribute" on the view aspx file?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. the type attribute I was referring to can be set in the list definition (Elements.xml) and list instance (Elements.xml) files. Normally when you create a list through VS UI, it lets you choose the type of list so normally you wouldn't need to do this explicitly.