# How do you change the Type attribute of a list?

Tags: 2013

I had an issue that was answered in [this question.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157030/no-new-event-button-in-sharepoint-calendar-view-of-custom-list/158837#158837) However the answer doesn't explain how to perform the fix. How do you change the Type attribute of a list?

Comment: Is it a list in site content you are talking about or a list you have first added in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `Type="109"` there in the **Elements.xml** if you are adding it using visual studio.

Otherwise check this link to add the type in there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119119/how-to-edit-a-list-template-in-sharepoint-2010